# Python Scripting Issue-how to show raster difference?

Tags: arcpy, raster

I am trying to use Python Script to detect change between two raster images using map algebra.

When I run the script, the output is the before image.  Do you have any advice?

Here is my code:

[image]

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, copy your code as text and use the format button in your question. Your example is *very* old, it looks 9.1 or 9.2.. which version of ArcGis are you using?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  A question asking for help with code should include a tested code snippet as text (not as an image).  Please [edit] your question to include your code snippet, and details of your ArcGIS version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you *sure* it's [Diff](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Diff/009z000000m3000000/) you want to use? The raster will have the values of the first raster where different and 0 where they are the same..

Your SA reference is very old, from ArcGis 10 rasters are objects and are used differently:

```
import os, sys, arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = 'x:\\ENVS117\\SkillsProject\\Jean&Miranda\\PythonTutorial.gdb'

if arcpy.CheckExtension("Spatial") == "Available":
    arcpy.AddMessage( "Checking out Spatial")
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
else:
    arcpy.AddMessage( "Unable to get spatial analyst extension")
    sys.exit(0)

Before = arcpy.Raster(r'x:\ENVS117\SkillsProject\Jean&Miranda\PythonTutorial.gdb\MS2015Band7')
After  = arcpy.Raster(r'x:\ENVS117\SkillsProject\Jean&Miranda\PythonTutorial.gdb\MS2017Band7')

Diff   = arcpy.sa.Diff(Before,After) # Using Diff
Diff.save(r'x:\ENVS117\SkillsProject\Jean&Miranda\PythonTutorial.gdb\Practice2')

Minus  = After - Before # using minus, could also be arcpy.sa.Abs(After - Before) for absolute value
Minus.save(r'x:\ENVS117\SkillsProject\Jean&Miranda\PythonTutorial.gdb\MinusPractice2')

arcpy.CheckInExtension("Spatial")
```

Sorry if the paths are wrong, I retyped them from your image.

After the map algebra is done on a raster you can make it permanent by calling the `.save()` method on the object.

Comment: Thank you so much, your script works great!

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1, but was watching tutorials from earlier versions of Arc Desktop.